# JSF 1.2 on JBoss 6 and EL expression not being resolved

Tags: java, jsf, el, jboss6.x

I have been hitting my head against the wall with this one for few hours already and I dont have a clue why this is happening...

Recently we have began process of moving from JBoss 4.2.3 to JBoss 6 Final. We are using JSF 1.2. I have sucessfully adapted application to new JBoss (mostly by removing some JARs from WEB-INF/lib and tunning web.xml a bit) and app starts nicely.

The problem is that some EL expressions are not being resolved, while others do. I also get 0 exceptions or warnings in the logs.

I have a bean called "mapContext" which is defined in one of the JSF xml config files. It is being created just fine. On my JSF page I have:

```
<h:inputHidden id="mapContextId" value="#{mapContext.webContextId}" />
```

and in the rendered page it becomes:

```
<input id="mapForm:mapContextId" type="hidden" name="mapForm:mapContextId" value="#{mapContext.webContextId}" />
```

As you can see, JSF tag is rendered just fine, but EL is not interpreted.

There are no logs in the server.log indicating any problems.

JSF 1.2, JSTL 1.2, Jboss 6, JDK 6.

Web.xml:

```
    <context-param>
    <param-name>org.jboss.jbossfaces.JSF_CONFIG_NAME</param-name>
    <param-value>Mojarra-1.2</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

More details:

Well I have doublechecked my code and configuration. Also I have added some logging to the Custom Variable Resolver I am using, to see what beans are used by JSF. Results are weird.

First of all I have enhanced my JSF page with different outputs, and it now looks like this:

```
    <h:inputHidden id="mapContextId1" value="#{mapContext}" />
<h:inputHidden id="mapContextId2" value="#{selectionPointSymbol.width}" />    
<h:inputHidden id="mapContextId" value="#{mapContext.webContextId}" />    
<h:inputHidden id="mapContextId3" value="#{selectionPointSymbol4.width}" />
```

and is rendered as:

```
<input type="hidden" name="mapForm" value="mapForm" />
<input id="mapForm:mapContextId1" type="hidden" name="mapForm:mapContextId1" value="#{mapContext}" />
<input id="mapForm:mapContextId2" type="hidden" name="mapForm:mapContextId2" value="#{selectionPointSymbol.width}" />
<input id="mapForm:mapContextId" type="hidden" name="mapForm:mapContextId" value="#{mapContext.webContextId}" />
<input id="mapForm:mapContextId3" type="hidden" name="mapForm:mapContextId3" value="#{selectionPointSymbol4.width}" />
```

I checked the logs and I can see that mapContext is being resolved just fine by non-standard JSF tags:

```
12:27:24,911 ERROR [mb.ags.adf.resolvers.AGSUserResolver] AGSUserResolver asked to resolve: mapContext
12:27:24,911 ERROR [mb.ags.adf.resolvers.AGSUserResolver] AGSUserResolver delegated to: com.sun.faces.el.ChainAwareVariableResolver@ab4f3c and resulted with: mb.ags.adf.map.MbWebContext@20
12:27:24,927 ERROR [mb.ags.adf.resolvers.AGSUserResolver] AGSUserResolver asked to resolve: mapContext
12:27:24,927 ERROR [mb.ags.adf.resolvers.AGSUserResolver] AGSUserResolver delegated to: com.sun.faces.el.ChainAwareVariableResolver@ab4f3c and resulted with: mb.ags.adf.map.MbWebContext@20
```

(lots of them in the logs).

But there is no single log about: selectionPointSymbol or selectionPointSymbol4 (no such bean defined at all!), which are only used in standard  tags.

Still no errors or warnings in the server log :(

---

More details: simple test.

JSF page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page buffer="96kb" autoFlush="true" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%>

<f:view>
<f:loadBundle basename="mb.ags.res.AGSClient" var="msg"/>
<html>
<head>
<title>*********</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" title="base" href="/gis/css/base-style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<style type="text/css">
  body { overflow:auto; }
</style>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

<div id="loading_table_container" style="position:absolute; text-align:center; left:0; top:0; width:100%; height:100%; z-index:20000; background-color:white;">
    <table id="loading" style="z-index:20001;" height="100%" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="middle" style="font-size: 12px">
                <img src="/gis/images/loading_big.gif" alt="Loading..." align="absmiddle"/><br/><br/>
                <h:outputText value="#{msg.welcome_page_map_client_loading}"/>
                <h:outputText id="mapContextId2" value="#{selectionPointSymbol.width}" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>        

<script>
    var url = "<%= redirectUrl %>";
    var refresh = "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"1000; URL=" + url + "\" />";
    document.writeln(refresh);
</script>
</body>
</html>
</f:view>
```

is rendered as:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>GIS</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" title="base" href="/gis/css/base-style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <style type="text/css">
      body { overflow:auto; }
    </style>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/gis/js/prototype.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/gis/js/scriptaculous/scriptaculous.js?load=effects"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/gis/js/ext/ext-prototype-adapter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/gis/js/ext/ext-all.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/gis/js/mb_errors.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript" src="/gis/js/esri_core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript" src="/gis/js/mapviewer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/gis/js/ExternalClient.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript" src="/gis/js/index_init.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="loading_table_container" style="position:absolute; text-align:center; left:0; top:0; width:100%; height:100%; z-index:20000; background-color:white;">
        <table id="loading" style="z-index:20001;" height="100%" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="middle" style="font-size: 12px">
                    <img src="/gis/images/loading_big.gif" alt="Loading..." align="absmiddle"/><br/><br/>
                    #{msg.welcome_page_map_client_loading}<span id="mapContextId2">#{selectionPointSymbol.width}</span>


                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>        

    <script>
        var url = "/gis/mapviewer.jsf?msid=1000005&uid=1&cid=1&mapContextId=1";
        var refresh = "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"1000; URL=" + url + "\" />";
        document.writeln(refresh);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Still no clue what is happening, as there are no logs indicating any problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ensure of the following things:

- You do not have servletcontainer-specific libraries like `el-*.jar` in `/WEB-INF/lib`.
- The `web.xml` is declared conform Servlet 3.0 specification (as JBoss 6 supports).
- The `web.xml` does not contain a context param of `com.sun.faces.expressionFactory` which points to a different (and apparently non-existing) EL implementation.

Comment: Oh man, thanks a lot!! web.xml had old specs attached, was still using 2.4!

Answer (score 0):

JSF silently returns the blank string if `mapContext` is not defined in your EL snippet.

Are you absolutely certain that mapContext is properly configured?  It is very easy to miss in a migration process.

Comment: More details added to my question.

Comment: How have you told JSF that the bean should be exposed under that name?  All the @Named stuff is not available until JSF 2.0

Comment: Go to the absolute basics.  A single page with #{mapContext} should end up in the beans toString.  Put a break point there to be certain.

Comment: Thorbjørn, I have added some interesting details to my post. Please check them out.